# How can I append values to a dataframe that don't exist

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to build out a reference frame. The frame will update with missing values on each iteration. I want to append rows to the referenceTable that are in partsToUpdate

If the ptno already exists then it should skip over it and only append the MISSING ptno's & their quantities

Example:

ReferenceTable

| Ptno | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 47750383 | 10 |
| 47909322 | 20 |
| 47907262 | 250 |
| 47895849 | 40 |
| 16400125 | 1200 |

partsToUpdate =

| Ptno | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 47907262 | 25 |
| 3568942 | 35 |
| 5145689 | 50 |
| 16400125 | 1400 |

I've tried merging the frames together but that just creates another ptno row with the previous value row added onto it, Like this: |

| Ptno | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 47750383 | 10 |
| 47909322 | 20 |
| 47907262 | 250 |
| 47895849 | 40 |
| 16400125 | 1200 |
| 47907262 | 250 |
| 3568942 | 35 |
| 5145689 | 50 |
| 16400125 | 1600 |

I was expecting something like:

Expected output

| Ptno | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 47750383 | 10 |
| 47909322 | 20 |
| 47907262 | 250 |
| 47895849 | 40 |
| 16400125 | 1200 |
| 3568942 | 35 |
| 5145689 | 50 |